# Can a Beast Master ranger's Animal Companion do extra damage from the Hunter's Mark spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, ranger, animal-companions

My Beast Master Ranger player is looking to use his *[hunter's mark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark)* bonus on his animal companion's attack action. Is the *hunter's mark* damage bonus strictly only for the ranger's attacks, or since the ranger is using their Attack action to command their animal companion to attack in their stead, can the animal companion get that bonus?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Only for the Ranger's Attacks

[Hunter's Mark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark) is cast on an initial target and provides a bonus on the caster's attacks. Emphasis is mine below:

> You choose a creature you can see within range and mystically mark it as **your quarry.** Until the spell ends, **you** deal an extra 1d6 damage to the target whenever **you** hit it with a weapon attack, and **you** have advantage on any Wisdom (Perception) or Wisdom (Survival) check you make to find it.

Just like the extra damage doesn't apply to your allies, it doesn't apply to your beast either (which is effectively another creature and an ally). It is for your attacks and your attacks only.

Comment: Which is a shame; if animal companion could benefit, beast master would be a bit more attractive.

Comment: It is worth noting that it is completely under your purview as the DM to decide that the (correct) ruling of our good NautArch need not affect beast masters in your world, since I also agree with Korvin in that beast masters need love in 5e.

Comment: @BlakeSteel The DM always has the option to houserule anything. But I don't see a huge balance issue in offloading the damage output to the Beast, while keeping the Bonus Action to change targets on the Ranger.

Comment: I was actually going to add this line to Beastmasters, to compensate: When you cast a spell that states the term "You", it is now amended to reflect "You or your Companion".--- I feel this would dramatically increase the interest in Beastmaster, while still being limited by Ranger spellcasting.

Comment: @DanielZastoupil I think that as long as you choose one at the casting then it's a reasonable addition to boost the Beastmaster a bit.

Comment: @NautArch even _both_ would not set the Beastmaster on the Battlemaster's power level

Answer (score 4):

I'm gonna say **No**, the animal companion can't claim the bonus damage. Hunter's Mark says...

> Until the spell ends, ***you*** deal an extra 1d6 damage to the target whenever you hit it with a weapon attack, (...)

Emphasis mine. You, not your allies or friendly creatures or mutual enemies. You, the caster of the spell.